# Mocking (actually, spying on) Sentry in a jest test in a Node.js project

Tags: jestjs, mocking, sentry, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock (well really, spyOn) Sentry with jest in a Node.js project and it is not working.

The `/debug-sentry` route just throws an exception, and interactively it correctly sends an exception to Sentry.  When I try to mock it like this, though, the `expect...toHaveBeenCalled` fails.  Am I not mocking this right? Suggestions?

```js
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
...
describe('failure modes', () => {
  it('send an exception to Sentry if exception thrown', async () => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(Sentry, 'captureException');
    const res = await request(server).get('/debug-sentry').expect('Content-Type', /text/).expect(500);
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This does not succeed, not sure why...
...
```

The code under test (I just added the `/debug-sentry` route to my server temporarily for testing):

```js
import express from 'express';
import { Express } from 'express-serve-static-core';

import { requestLogger } from '@/utils/request_logger';
import {
  initialize_exception_reporting,
  initialize_error_reporting,
  send_exception_message
  } from '@/utils/exception_reporting';

export async function createServer(): Promise<Express> {
  const server = express();

  initialize_exception_reporting(server);

  server.use(requestLogger);

  // error customization, if request is invalid
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any,@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  server.use((err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    res.status(err.status).json({
      error: {
        type: 'request_validation',
        message: err.message,
        errors: err.errors,
      },
    });
  });

  server.get("/debug-sentry", (req, res) => {
    throw new Error("My first Sentry error!");
  });

  initialize_error_reporting(server);

  return server;
}
```

and the code setting up Sentry:

```js
import Express from 'express';
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";
import * as Tracing from "@sentry/tracing";

export function initialize_exception_reporting(server: Express.Express) {
  Sentry.init({
    integrations: [],
  });
  server.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
}

export function initialize_error_reporting(server: Express.Express) {
  server.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
}

export function send_exception_message(message: string) {
  Sentry.captureMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the code that you are testing.

Comment: the ```captureException``` mock isn't mocking out any code in your example.

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas that's correct, it's spying on an imported function.  I've updated my post to make that a little more clear.

Comment: Someone from the Sentry team has recommended that spying on Sentry won't work for this, as the internal exception handling doesn't use the public API.  They suggest using something like `nock` to watch for the expect network activity.